# Does checking "A portion of these dividends is U.S. Government interest." matter when filing tax in Washington state?

Tags: united-states, taxes, interest, government-bonds, washington

I'm filing my taxes in the US since I reside in WA state and I'm being asked by TurboTax whether a portion of these dividends is U.S. Government interest:

[image]

Does checking "A portion of these dividends is U.S. Government interest." matter when filing tax in Washington state?

Answer (score 0):

Federal notes interest is exempt from State income taxes, but not from the Federal income tax (See [the IRS Tax Topic 403](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc403)):

> Interest income from Treasury bills, notes and bonds - This interest is subject to federal income tax, but is exempt from all state and local income taxes.

So, since there's no personal income tax in WA, it doesn't matter for you how you answer.